# Unable to read mpx file

Tags: metapost

This is file of LaTeX:

```
verbatimtex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, longtable, verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\rm
etex

prologues := 3;
u=.5cm;

beginfig(1);
z0=(0,0);
label.bot(btex $A$ etex, z0);
endfig;

end
```

This is command, that I use for compile of mp-file in cmd (Windows 10): `mpost DifGemFig.mp -tex=latex`
I save file in *Notepad++* with UTF-8.
And I get an error:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.02 (MiKTeX 22.8.28)
(C:/Users/mrPlag/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(C:/Users/mrPlag/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./DifGemFig.mpfatal: Command failed: tex --parse-first-line --interaction=nonstopmode mpM7rFx1.tex; see mpxerr.log
>> DifGemFig.mp
>> DifGemFig.mpx
! ! Unable to read mpx file.
l.18 label.bot(btex
                    $A$ etex, z0);
Transcript written on DifGemFig.log.
```

Why do I see this error? There are no mpx-files in directory. On other PC btex is work.

Comment: You have the command back-to-front.  It should be `mpost -tex=latex DifGemFig.mp`.  If you put the `-tex` option *after* the file, MP will try to read process your DifGemFig.mp with plain TeX, hence the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Metapost program `mpost` processes its arguments left to right.  So when you called it like this:

```
mpost DifGemFig.mp -tex=latex
```

it processed `DifGemFig.mp` with the default TeX engine, which is plain `tex`.  But in your case this failed because you have a `verbatimtex` block that needs the LaTeX engine instead.  If you had looked in `mpxerr.log` as the error message suggests:

```
Command failed: tex [...] mpM7rFx1.tex; see mpxerr.log
```

then you would have found lots of errors saying that `\documentclass` was an undefined control sequence, etc., might have given you a clue!

So what you need to do is to run:

```
mpost -tex=latex DifGemFig.mp
```

Now the first argument tells `mpost` to change to using the LaTeX engine and the second is your file, which will be processed correctly.

If this feels a bit too hard, then the alternative is to use `lualatex` and the `luamplib` package to produce your stand-alone Metapost graphics, like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    dotlabel.urt("$A$", origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF file that looks like this:

[image]

### Notes

- None of the packages in the MWE are needed for `lualatex`
- ... except you might want to add `amsmath` and `unicode-math`
- The `mplibtextextlabel` option automatically passes strings in labels through Latex (as if you had typed `textext("string")`) so you do not need to use `btex ... etex` any more.